# vbulletin CMS section widget showing all sections

Tags: content-management-system, widget, vbulletin

Edit: I just want to say hi first! stop removing it! Hi!!!! :)

I'd like to do something very simple I think but cannot get it to work.

Here is my section structure in my vBulletin CMS

```
HOME
    Section 1
        Section 1.1
        Section 1.2
        Section 1.3
    Section 2
        Section 2.1
        Section 2.2
        Section 2.3
```

When I add the widget "Section Navigation- JS enhanced" it shows:

```
HOME
    Section 1
    Section 2
```

When I click on Section 1 it shows:

```
HOME
    Section 1
        Section 1.1
        Section 1.2
        Section 1.3
    Section 2
```

Great but I would like to hide Section 2 and the other way around, hide section 1 when I click on section 2.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

This is "not possible".

I mean : you could not achieve what you want without hacking/modifying vBulletin code.

So, one way to do that could be to change the SQL query in

> pacakges/vbcms/widget/sectionnavext.php

to only print the section you need to print.